# Inequalities & Algebra Question Linear Programming

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality

I was given the following question about the Adult Child fares on a bus service and I got stuck mid-way through solving.

> A child's bus fare is cheaper than the adult fare but is more than half the adult fare. The total cost of a single journey for an adult and two children is £1.20. 
>   
> Adult fares are all multiples of 10 p.
>   
> What is the adult fare?
>   
> **[A]** 30 p
>   
> **[B]** 40 p
>   
> **[C]** 50 p
>   
> **[D]** 60 p
>   
> **[E]** 70 p

This was my method.

Using $A$ for adult, and $C$ for child, I produced an equation.

$$A + 2C = 120$$

> A child's bus fare is cheaper than the adult fare but is more than half the adult fare.

This gave me the following inequality:

$$C > \frac{1}{2}A$$
$$2C > A$$

so in this instance, $A < 60$, eliminating D and E as possible choices.

I can't seem to progress further from this. I know A, B or C are one of the correct questions but I can't seem to get to that step.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have two inequalities: $C > A/2$ and $C<A$.

Now, $C < A \implies A+2C < 3A \implies 3A > 120 \implies A > 40$.

On the other hand, $C>A/2 \implies A+2C>2A \implies 2A < 120 \implies A<60$.

So the correct choice is [C], i.e., $A = 50$p (and $C=35$p).

Comment: Fantastic answer. Understood much better - uprated too! Many thanks!